# Foundation customizing scss classes

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to customize scss of foundation to have a two different classes for topbar. I have limited knowledge of scss therefore changing _settings.scss was very easy first step, which has the problem that it changes global style. I would like to do something like following without messing up global styles.

```
.my-topbar-first {
$topbar-bg-color: $red;
@extend .top-bar;

}

.my-topbar-second {
$topbar-bg-color: $green;
@extend .top-bar;

}
```

Whats the elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try to remove from `.top-bar` the `background-color` and add it to each class manualy - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p6L1pk7z/). Or override it with `!important`

Answer (score 1):

when you are using `$topbar-bg-color: $red;` it set the `$topbar-bg-color` variable to what you have in `$red` variable.when you are using it again, it messed up the last setting.
so instead,
you have to do like this :

```
.my-topbar-first {
 background-color: $red;
 @extend .top-bar;

}

.my-topbar-second {
 background-color: $green;
 @extend .top-bar;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are duplicating code when extending `.top-bar` in both class names . A more DRY approach would be like this :

```
.my-topbar-first,
.my-topbar-second {
  @extend .top-bar;
}

.my-topbar-first {
 background-color: $red;
}

.my-topbar-second {
 background-color: $green;
}
```

When using `@extend` or `@include` they should always be on the first line were you declare your properties , example:

```
my-topbar-second {
     @extend .top-bar;
     background-color: $green;
     color: $white;
     font-size: $top-bar-fontsize;
    }
```

If you have more instances of `.top-bar-foo` you can actually write a for loop, example :

```
$class-slug: top-bar;

@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  .#{$class-slug}-#{$i} {
     background-color: $color-#{$i};
  }
}
```

You get :

```
.top-bar-1 {
  background-color: $color-1;
}

.top-bar-2 {
  background-color: $color-2;
}
```

Hope this helped . If you want to learn more about Scss go on Hugo Giraudel's blog http://hugogiraudel.com/ and learn from the best .